# Sharing a queue among Java EE web apps?

Tags: rest, jakarta-ee, queue, jms

I have REST server web app that captures data, persists it, and then adds it to a queue.

I have another web app that should take items from this queue and transmit them to clients every X seconds.

How would I go about implementing this with Java EE?

Comment: you mean on the same server ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would read up on [JMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Message_Service) and look for the concrete implementation in your EE container of choice.